# commandLink in primefaces datatable doesn't work if I add the filteredValue attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable with a `<p:commandLink>` in each row. The user clicks it to see a different page with details about the record he selected. It was working fine until I add a filteredValue in my datatable. I need this attribute (filteredValue) in order to correctly filter and sort my datatable, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307346/primefaces-datatable-doesnt-work-with-filter-sort).

But after adding this attribute, my commandLink stops working. How can I make it work with the attribute?

Here's my datatable:

```
<p:dataTable var="prot" value="#{myBean.listaProtocolos}" rows="15" filteredValue="#{myBean.listaProtocolosFiltrados}" sortBy="#{prot.dataEntradaArea}" sortFunction="#{myBean.sortXMLDatas}" sortOrder="descending" paginator="true" style="font-size: 0.9em;" paginatorPosition="bottom">
  <p:column filterBy="${prot.nrProtocolo}" filterMatchMode="contains" width="8%" style="text-align:center">
    <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
    <p:commandLink action="#{myBean.verDetalhesProtocolo}" process="@this messages" update="@this messages">
      <h:outputText value="#{prot.nrProtocolo}" style="text-decoration: underline;"/>
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.nrProtocolo}" value="#{prot.nrProtocolo}" />
    </p:commandLink>
  </p:column>
(etc)
```

and the relevant pieces of myBean:

```
public void verDetalhesProtocolo() {
    for(ProtocoloMY pro : this.listaProtocolos){
        if(pro.getNrProtocolo().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(this.nrProtocolo.trim())) {
            this.protocolo = new ProtocoloMY(pro);
            break;
        }
    }
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("detalhes_protocolo_processo.xhtml");
    //(This method isn't even called when I add the attribute filteredValue to my datatable)

public String getNrProtocolo() {
    return nrProtocolo;
}

public void setNrProtocolo(String nrProtocolo) {
    this.nrProtocolo = nrProtocolo;
}
    public List<ProtocoloMY> getListaProtocolos() {
    return listaProtocolos;
}

public List<ProtocoloMY> getListaProtocolosFiltrados() {
    return listaProtocolosFiltrados;
}

public void setListaProtocolosFiltrados(List<ProtocoloMY> listaProtocolosFiltrados) {
    this.listaProtocolosFiltrados = listaProtocolosFiltrados;
}

public void setListaProtocolos(List<ProtocoloMY> listaProtocolos) {
    this.listaProtocolos = listaProtocolos;
}
```

And I almost forgot to say: There's some network traffic happening when I click the link, but nothing is shown in my backend console and the method in my bean isn't called.
[image: browser's console indicating some data travelled to the backend]

I'm running primefaces v6.0.

Comment: What PrimeFaces version do you use? Did you try to use commandButton or ajax rowSelect event instead command link? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: Hi, I'm using version 6.0. I tried commandbutton with same results. Didn't try rowSelect yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PrimeFaces to be able to track which row by its unique id you need to add the attribute rowKey="#{row.id}" to your p:datatable using whatever value in your row POJO that makes it unique.

Comment: I tried both the Object (prot) and a String as parameters, but it didn't work =(. The same behavior happens.

    <p:commandLink action="#{myBean.verDetalhesProtocolo(prot.nrProtocolo)}" process="@this messages" update="@this messages">
      <h:outputText value="#{prot.nrProtocolo}" style="text-decoration: underline;"/>
    </p:commandLink>

Comment: I noticed you are also missing the rowKey="" attribute on the datatable which should be like rowKey="#{prot.id}" or whaetever field makes a row identifiable and unique.

Comment: I'll test and ASAP! Unfortunately the code is trapped inside my company's offices, so it'll happen next Monday :)

Comment: Hi @melloware , thanks again and apologies for taking so long. Adding the rowkey attribute to my datatable seems to be the right answer! Should I mark this answer as correct or is there a way to transform this comment in an answer?

Comment: @BrunoLamps I corrected my answer and yes you should mark it as the solution.  Thanks!